¿Por qué el método Members.insert de la API AdminDirectory de Google no reconoce algunos correos que no son de @gmail?
Estoy intentando automatizar el proceso de suscripción de usuarios en un Grupo de Google. Para ello he programado una función que se lanza cada cierto tiempo en Google Apps Script. La misma busca en el correo los mensajes no leídos con un label específico o con un asunto específico. Todo eso funciona maravillosamente.
El problema es que la inserción da error con algunos correos que no son de @gmail. No con todos, porque con otros correos distintos de @gmail también funciona.
Esta es la función que dispara el trigger:
function triggerForEmail() {
  const threads = GmailApp.search('is:unread AND {label:"Confirmado" subject:"Re: Suscripción al boletín semanal" subject:"Confirmando"}');
  let newMembers=[]
  for (const thread of threads) {
    const messages = thread.getMessages()
    for (const message of messages) {
      newMembers.push({'email':message.getFrom().toLowerCase(),role: "MEMBER"})
      message.markRead();
    }
  }
  if (typeof newMembers !== 'undefined' && newMembers.length > 0) {
    addUserstoGroup(newMembers);
  }
}


Y esta es la función que inserta los usuarios en el Grupo de Google:
function addUserstoGroup(newUsers) {
  var groupId = "MIGRUPO@midominio.com";
  var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(groupId);
  var newMembers=[];
    newUsers.forEach(u => {
        try { 
          var hasMember = group.hasUser(u.email); 
          if (!hasMember){
            var mStatus=AdminDirectory.Members.insert(u, groupId); 
            Logger.log("Agregado: %s \n",u.email);
            newMembers.push({'email':u.email});
          }else{
            Logger.log("Existe: %s \n",u.email); 
          }
        } catch(e) {
          Logger.log("Error: %s Email: %s\n",e,u.email);
        }
    });
    if (typeof newMembers !== 'undefined' && newMembers.length > 0) {
      sendToNewUsers(newMembers);
    } else {
      Logger.log("Nada nuevo");
    }
}

El problema ocurre en esta línea:
var mStatus=AdminDirectory.Members.insert(u, groupId); 

Con ciertos correos da el error siguiente:

Error: Exception: Invalid email: algunosCorreos@queNoSonDeGmail

No es un problema de los correos. Los mismos existen, de hecho, los tomo de mensajes de confirmación enviados por los usuarios de los mismos y si los agrego a mano en Google Groups se agregan. Es evidente que hay un fallo en la API.
He preguntado en SO en inglés, sin éxito ninguno. He preguntado en Issue Tracker y tampoco me dan respuesta luego de haberme sugerido varias cosas que he ido descartando. Quisiera encontrar el motivo de este fallo para poder automatizar esta tediosa tarea.

Encontré la solución a este problema gracias a esta respuesta.
Parece que cuando se utiliza el método getFrom()  en una tarjeta, aparece el nombre pero no la dirección de correo electrónico, o sea, algo así: Nombre Apellido <elEmail@example.com>. Era por ese motivo por el que en algunos casos daba error, ya que en vez de elEmail@example.com tomaba Nombre Apellido.
La solución, mientras lo corrigen en la API de Gmail1, es buscar la dirección correcta, que se encontraría  entre los carácteres < y  >.
Al poner la función así, el error ha desaparecido:
function triggerForEmail() {
    const threads = GmailApp.search('is:unread AND {label:"Confirmado" subject:"Re: Suscripción al boletín semanal" subject:"Confirmando"}');
    let newMembers = []
    for (const thread of threads) {
        const messages = thread.getMessages()
        for (const message of messages) {
          var from = message.getFrom().split("<")[1].split(">")[0];
            newMembers.push({
                'email': from.toLowerCase(),
                role: "MEMBER"
            })
            message.markRead();
        }
    }
    if (typeof newMembers !== 'undefined' && newMembers.length > 0) {
        addUserstoGroup(newMembers);
    }
}


Notas

El caso está reportado en Issue Tracker.

